# Replace substring into a string using objective C

Tags: arrays, string, replace, substring

I am trying to replace my custom IP address with the existing URL IP address. How can replace the my IP address with the existing IP. Please find the code snippet below

```
 - (IBAction)btnSubmit:(UIButton *)sender {

        NSString *ipAdd = [_txtIPAddress text];
        NSLog(@"My entered IP Address is %@", ipAdd);

        NSLog(@"Current pointing server value is %@", [ConnManager activeEndpoint]);

        NSLog([App appDelegate].isConfigured  ? @"Yes" : @"No");

        NSArray *listItems = [[ConnManager activeEndpoint] componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];

        ConnManager *conn = [[ConnManager alloc] init];

        NSMutableString *configuredUrl = nil;
        [configuredUrl setString:@""];

        for ( NSInteger i =0; i < listItems.count; i++) {
            if(i != 2) {
                NSMutableString * arrayElement = [(NSMutableString*)listItems objectAtIndex:i];
                NSMutableString *str = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat: @"%@/", arrayElement];
                [configuredUrl appendString:str];
            } else {
                NSMutableString *configstr = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat: @"%@", ipAdd];

                NSLog(@"ConfigString %@", configstr);


//How to replace the my ip address with the array index[2]
 configuredUrl = [configuredUrl stringByAppendingFormat:configstr];
            NSLog(@"Configured Url after apppending %@", configuredUrl);
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this shorter version, it replaces everything after the line 
`NSLog([App appDelegate].isConfigured  ? @"Yes" : @"No");`

```
  NSMutableArray *listItems = [[[ConnManager activeEndpoint] pathComponents] mutableCopy];
  listItems[2] = ipAdd;
  NSString *configuredUrl = [NSString pathWithComponents:listItems];
  NSLog(@"%@", configuredUrl);
```

or, if `activeEndpoint` is an URL, still easier

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[ConnManager activeEndpoint]];
 NSString *configuredURL = [[[NSURL alloc] initWithScheme:[url scheme] host:ipAdd path:[url path]] absoluteString];
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works but I am getting URL as http:/xx.x.xxx.xx/xx/xx. How can I insert one more slash after http:

Answer (score 0):

It is often easier to leave the parsing of URLs to a system class. If you can, I would suggest using `NSURLComponents`. For example:

```
NSURLComponents *URLComponents = 
     [NSURLComponents componentsWithString:[ConnManager activeEndpoint]];
URLComponents.host = [_txtIPAddress text];
NSString *configuredURL = URLComponents.string;
```